# Vim Return to last point in file

Tags: vim, vimrc

can anybody provide an explanation as to what this is doing or point me to vimdocs? `line("'\"")`

```
function! ResCur()$
  if line("'\"") <= line("$")
    normal! g`" 
    return 1
  endif$
endfunction
```

the function is for returning the caret to the same line when opening a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"` is escaped with a backslash because `'"` is surrounded with double quotes.

`:help '"` says:

```
To the cursor position when last exiting the current
buffer.  Defaults to the first character of the first
line.  See last-position-jump for how to use this
for each opened file.
Only one position is remembered per buffer, not one
for each window.  As long as the buffer is visible in
a window the position won't be changed.
```